# Jsoup and Android

Tags: android, jsoup

I ve looked at the [JSoup Selector Overview](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) documentation but I'm still having problems. I want to get information from a webpage and this information is stored in a table. Once I retrieve this I want to split into the individual rows in order to use it later; but I can't seem to do it.

I have JSoup running fine but it doesn't work when I try to reference the particular table I want by Id such as:

```
try 
                {
                    Document doc = Jsoup.connect( myHtml ).get();

                    Elements pTag = doc.select( "table#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tblPasses" );
                    //Elements links = doc.select( "a[href]" );
                    String pTagString = pTag.html();

                    // Set the textview to the results of the Jsoup query
                    setData( pTagString );

                    // Reset msg
                    msg = null;
                    msg = handler.obtainMessage( UPDATE_UI );
                    handler.sendMessage( msg );

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Here is the segment of HTML code Im attempting to get to:

```
<table id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tblPasses" class="standardTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" rules="cols" border="2" style="background-color:White;border-color:Gray;border-width:2px;border-style:Solid;border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr class="tablehead" style="border-width:0px;border-style:None;">
    <td valign="middle" rowspan="2">Date</td><td id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MagHeader" valign="middle">Brightness</td><td align="center" colspan="3">Start</td><td align="center" colspan="3">Highest point</td><td align="center" colspan="3">End</td>
</tr><tr class="tablehead">
    <td id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MagHeader2" align="center">(<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_linkMagnitude" title="show definition of this term" href="glossary.aspx?term=magnitude&amp;lat=54.5156&amp;lng=-6.06863&amp;loc=Unspecified&amp;alt=0&amp;tz=GMT">mag</a>)</td><td align="center">Time</td><td><a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_linkAltitude" title="show definition of this term" href="glossary.aspx?term=altitude&amp;lat=54.5156&amp;lng=-6.06863&amp;loc=Unspecified&amp;alt=0&amp;tz=GMT">Alt.</a></td><td><a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_linkAzimuth" title="show definition of this term" href="glossary.aspx?term=azimuth&amp;lat=54.5156&amp;lng=-6.06863&amp;loc=Unspecified&amp;alt=0&amp;tz=GMT">Az.</a></td><td align="center">Time</td><td>Alt.</td><td>Az.</td><td align="center">Time</td><td>Alt.</td><td>Az.</td>
```

This is only part of the table, there's a lot more but for now I want to get at this table and it's first row. Any thoughts?

***Update***

I tried this:

```
Elements table = doc.select( "table#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tblPasses" );
Element first_Row = table.first();

//Elements links = doc.select( "a[href]" );
String first_Row_Strg = first_Row.html().toString();

// Set the textview to the results of the Jsoup query
setData( first_Row_Strg );
```

But it actually returns the whole table and not the first row. Should I try aiming at the actual identifier of the row in the table? If so how do you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

think differently, select directly child from parent.

`Element first_row = doc.select("table#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tblPasses tr").first();`

Comment: Hi mate - just to update you - yeah I got it working although my exact method is bait round about as I decided to reference each component on top of the previous. Like table > rows > first row > firstCell using a[href] etc etc. Thanks for the help :D